# Oozie Workflow with Pig, Hive and unix

Tags: hive, apache-pig, cloudera, oozie, bigdata

i am new to oozie and i want to write a workflow with actions as pig, hive and unix command. I am not getting any examples with these 3 actions, if you guys can provide some examples or links it will be nice.
Thanks

Comment: I was about to point you to the "Hooked on Hadoop" blog series about Oozie -- but the `blogspot.com` site appears to be AWOL  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oozie examples for all the standard action types come bundled with Oozie distribution itself. Anyways, download the [Oozie examples archive using this link](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/public/org/apache/oozie/oozie-examples/3.3.2-cdh4.5.0.2-SNAPSHOT/oozie-examples-3.3.2-cdh4.5.0.2-20140428.112158-28-examples.tar.gz) and check it out.

Comment: @IndranilGanguly You can also visit the apache [oozie repository](https://github.com/apache/oozie/tree/master/examples/src/main/apps), it will always be update. Thanks.